# JS code doesn't work in Firefox or Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to embedd an iFrame with a small js-app inside on a website, but in FF and IE, the js doen't work (although it does show the html interface). Is there a way to solve this? Chrome and Safari work fine.

Edit: I didnt post any code initially because I thought there might be a standard procedure for FF or IE. 
In the meanwhile I found out that my app doesn't work AT ALL in FF or IE...bummer. I left out the CSS, because the app should work nevertheless. It is a financial calculator for debt conversion. Any ideas?

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



      <style type="text/css">


*CSS Stuff*

        </style>


    </head>
    <body>

        <script language="JavaScript">
<!--

            var res = document.getElementById('r');



            function ersatzrate() {
                var zinsalt = document.test.zinsalt.value;
                var zeitalt = parseInt(document.test.zeitalt.value);
                var ratealt = parseInt(document.test.ratealt.value);


               StringText = zinsalt.toString();                       
               AusgabeText = StringText.replace(",",".");
               zinsalt=parseFloat(AusgabeText);



               var zinsneu = document.test.zinsneu.value; 

               StringText2 = zinsneu.toString();                      
               AusgabeText2 = StringText2.replace(",",".");
               zinsneu=(parseFloat(AusgabeText2)/100/12);

               zinsalt = zinsalt/100/12; 

                if (0.21 > zinsalt > 0 && 60 > zeitalt > 0 && 2000 > ratealt > 0 && zinsalt>zinsneu) {

                    var rkb = ratealt * zeitalt;               
                    document.test.rkb.value = rkb;

                    var bw = ratealt * ((Math.pow((zinsalt+1), zeitalt) - 1) / (Math.pow((zinsalt + 1), zeitalt) * zinsalt));  
                    var bw = bw.toFixed(2);
                    // document.test.bw.value = bw;

                    var rateneu =  bw*((Math.pow((zinsneu + 1), zeitalt) * zinsneu)/(Math.pow((zinsneu+1), zeitalt) - 1)); 
                    //rateneu = rateneu*1.01; 
                    var rateneu = rateneu.toFixed(2);                   
                    document.test.rateneu.value = rateneu;


                    var rkbneu = rateneu*zeitalt;
                    var rkbneu = rkbneu.toFixed(2);
                    document.test.rkbneu.value = rkbneu;


                    var ersparnis = (rkb-rkbneu);
                    var ersparnis = ersparnis.toFixed(2);
                    document.test.ersparnis.value = ersparnis;    
                }                               
            }
//-->
        </script>
        <div class="container">
        <form name="test">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><span class="number">1</span>title</legend>          

            <br><br>
            Old interest:<input onkeyup="ersatzrate()" type="text" name="zinsalt" value="8,00" size="10">
            time:<input onkeyup="ersatzrate()" type="text" name="zeitalt" value="36" size="10">
            old rate:<input onkeyup="ersatzrate()" type="text" name="ratealt" value="300" size="10"><br>
            <br>  
            <span class="number">2</span>New credit
            <br>
            <br>
            new interest:<input onkeyup="ersatzrate()" type="text" name="zinsneu" value="2,99" size="10"><br>
            <br>
            Neue monthly rate:  <output name="rateneu" ></output><br>    
            <br>
            <span class="number">3</span>Ersparnis                         
            cost of debt right now:  <output name="rkb"></output><br>  <br>
            cost new debt  <output name="rkbneu"></output><br>    
            <div align="right">
                   <br>
            _______
            </div>
            <br>


            <b>savings comparde to old debt: <output name="ersparnis"></output></b>
            </fieldset>
            </form>        
         </div>    



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add some of your code so we can see hwat you have done

Comment: Impossible to help unless you post the faulty code. Don't look for incompatibilities in IE, it is the only one of the browsers you mentioned that already existed when IFRAMEs were created

Comment: the one thing that bugs me most, is that in IE or FF, it doesn't even show the standard preset values of the html. something has to be pretty wrong.

Comment: F12 and read the console. *"It doesn't work"* isn't good enough here. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: So this question has nothing to do with iframe, it's just the js itself that has issues. Can you update the title please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the F12 debuuger, didn't know that.

The problem was that in the HTML I didn't specify an "id=foo", I just specified a "name=foo" and Internet Explorer can't handle that.